# How to Fix : BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-zipfile

I have a file that I downloaded from Kaggle, but when I want to extract the zip file, an error occurs
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
I have made sure that the archive file that I have is .zip, I have tried various ways but it doesn't work.

Here is the code syntax I use:

```
# importing required modules
from zipfile import ZipFile
mydataset = "batuguntingkertas.zip"
#opening the zip file in READ mode
with ZipFile(mydataset, 'r') as zip:
  zip.printdir()

  #extracting all the files
  print('Extracting all the files now...')
  zip.extractall()
  print('Done!')


 
Result  :
```

BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 mydataset = "batuguntingkertas.zip"
2 #opening the zip file in READ mode
----> 3 with ZipFile(mydataset, 'r') as zip:
4   zip.printdir()
5

---

1 frames

---

/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
1334             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
1335         if not endrec:
-> 1336             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
1337         if self.debug > 1:
1338             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

```
NOTE : Colabs


How to Fix BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: How you know it is valid zip file?

Comment: Just putting `.zip` on the end doesn't make it a zip file. A zip file is a specific format produced by software compliant with the zip specification. For that matter some files that don't end in `.zip` actually are zip files, like java jar files that typically end in `.jar`. Try testing the file with a command-line program like `unzip -t`.

Comment: Agree with @PresidentJamesK.Polk - you first need to verify that the file you downloaded in actually a zip file before attempting to use python to extract its contents.  Start by running `file batuguntingkertas.zip` to check that it is actually a zip file, then run `unzip -t batuguntingkertas.zip` to check that it is well formed.